# Record silence at the beginning and end of a recording

Tags: python, discord, pycord

Used [this example](https://guide.pycord.dev/voice/receiving) to record audio from a voice channel. Everything works, in the output I get a separate audio track for each speaking user.

Next, I want to overlay the audio files on top of each other and glue the conversation in the channel into one file, but as a result, all the voices in the file sound simultaneously, although in fact the users speak in turn.

This is because `py-cord` does not record silence at the beginning and end of the user's audio recording.

Thus, if three people say something in turn, then as a result the recordings of their speech will have different lengths and because of this they are mixed into one heap.

How ​​can I record audio files of the same length for all users in a channel?

##### UPDATE:

This is a fragment of the [`recv_decoded_audio`](https://docs.pycord.dev/en/stable/_modules/discord/voice_client.html#VoiceClient.is_playing) method from the [`discord.VoiceClient`](https://docs.pycord.dev/en/stable/api/voice.html#discord.VoiceClient) class. From here it can be understood that the silence between the user's speech is added by calculating the time between individual fragments of the user's speech.
Here's my code:

```py
def recv_decoded_audio(self, data):
    if data.ssrc not in self.user_timestamps:
        self.user_timestamps.update({data.ssrc: data.timestamp})
        # Add silence when they were not being recorded.
        silence = 0
    else:
        silence = data.timestamp - self.user_timestamps[data.ssrc] - 960
        self.user_timestamps[data.ssrc] = data.timestamp

    data.decoded_data = (
        struct.pack("<h", 0) * silence * opus._OpusStruct.CHANNELS
        + data.decoded_data
    )
       
    . . .
```

In this case, it makes sense that I can replace the line `silence = 0` with this code:

```py
. . .
self.start_recording_timestamp = int(datetime.now().timestamp())
. . .

silence = data. Timestamp - self.start_recording_timestamp
```

This will indeed add the user's silence at the beginning of the recording, but for some reason, instead of 5 seconds, a minute of silence is immediately added there.
Is it correct to implement the addition of silence at the beginning of the recording, while not changing the library files?

How do I correctly calculate the silence time at the beginning of a recording?

Answer (score -3):

I suggest you make a function that does this, AND combines a recording of silence in the beginning and end of the article. For example, you could name the beginning silence as `beginning_silence.wav` and the other `ending_silence.wav`, if your files are `.wav`. I suggest you look at this article: [https://programmerblog.net/join-wav-audio-files-using-python/#:~:text=The%20combined%20generated%20file%201%201.%20Install%20Python,join%20wav%20files%20using%20python%20to%20one%20file](https://programmerblog.net/join-wav-audio-files-using-python/#:%7E:text=The%20combined%20generated%20file%201%201.%20Install%20Python,join%20wav%20files%20using%20python%20to%20one%20file)

Comment: This doesn't answer OP's question.